# Laravel API route requires Session

Tags: php, laravel

I used **Laravel** only for **API requests**. So i have deleted the Session classes from **Kernel.php**.

My routes are in web.php.
Now i need to create web pages. So i moved current routes to api.php, and this occurs error.

> Class session.store does not exist

Why api routes tries to use Session? Because api calls don't need Session.
How can i switch off session for api routes? Because api calls accepting more than 100 requests per second.

Comment: it was already commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's default guard is set to `web`. When you use only API endpoints, you need to change your `defaults.guards` in `config/auth.php` to `api` for example. You can see in `app/Http/Kernel.php` that `$middlewareGroups` for `api` does not includes session middlewares so they are not used.

If you use the default api driver `token` then you need to add a `api_token` column to your users table and include this parameter on the request like `http://localhost/api/user?api_token={token}`.

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#introduction. Seems that it changed in Laravel 7 but I don't know which version you are using.